# Building Ember app gives me error, Cannot read property 'pkg' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

I was trying to compile a website frontend from 2015 that utilizes an old version of ember.js and node.js. The instructions state to run `make build`, which in turn would run `ember build dist`. Though when the command is ran, it gives me this error.

```
Cannot read property 'pkg' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pkg' of null
    at Function.Addon.resolvePath (/home/pyah/pyah/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:347:18)
    at Function.Addon.lookup (/home/pyah/pyah/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:362:22)
    at /home/pyah/pyah/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:222:34
    at visit (/home/pyah/pyah/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/utilities/DAG.js:23:3)
    at DAG.topsort (/home/pyah/pyah/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/utilities/DAG.js:82:7)
    at Project.initializeAddons (/home/pyah/pyah/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:220:9)
    at Project.eachAddonCommand (/home/pyah/pyah/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:249:10)
    at module.exports (/home/pyah/pyah/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/lookup-command.js:53:13)
    at CLI.<anonymous> (/home/pyah/pyah/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:36:26)
    at $$$internal$$tryCatch (/home/pyah/pyah/client/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:490:16)
```

This error is shown even if just `ember` is ran in terminal.

Node.js version: `v6.12.0`

npm version: `6.14.15`

ember-cli version: `0.1.5`

Comment: which version of ember-cli?

Comment: or is this pre-ember-cli?

Comment: ember-cli version added, it is version 0.1.5